# How to identify the mobile heap memory on runtime using j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, runtime, heap-memory

I developing j2me application. In this application i need to identify the mobile heap memory on runtime. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```

- [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html)